# Clone row values from previous one to current one

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have this below class where i am cloning rows with values from previous rows to current one. I am able to clone the rows but at every clone i am getting the 1st row values.

I am not getting the values of the row which i clicked. I am afraid i am not able to get the row index.

```
Class - 


       public void testclone(){

            for (Integer idx=0; idx<sdf; idx++)
            {
                Test_Detail__c a = wrappers[0].werc.clone(false, true, false, false);
                wrappers.add(new TestWrapper(nextIdent++,a));
            } 
        }
```

Comment: are these rows static or dynamic? if dynamic then, you can use <apex:variable> to get the index and pass the index to controller

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Test_Detail__c a = wrappers[idx].testserv.clone(false, true, false, false);` ?

Comment: all the rows are dynamic...

Comment: then put your dynamic coding into the question

Comment: Hi Oleksiy.. I didnt get u..

Comment: Done Santanu.. i hv added addrow method and vf page..

Answer (score 0):

Currently you referencing always to wrappers[0], should change it.

Test_Detail__c a = wrappers[**idx**].testserv.clone(false, true, false, false);

Comment: Still i am getting the values of 1st row ..I think we need to pass the rowindex instead of <apex:param name="addCount" value="1" assignTo="{!addCount}" />

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Does the clone should work only on specific row? should it clone all the rows?

Comment: whichever row i click .. it should clone that row..

Comment: what we need to pass?

Comment: You should pass the row index.

 <apex:param name="addCount" value="{!wrapper.ident}" assignTo="{!addCount}" />

later in the function you need to write:

for (Integer idx=0; idx<addCount; idx++)
            {
  if(wrapper[idx].indIdent == addCount){
                 Test_Detail__c a = wrappers[idx].testserv.clone(false, true, false, false);
                 wrappers.add(new TestWrapper(nextIdent++,a));
  }
            }